empty string in get-request
I have the following controlelr in my Web-API-project:
// GET: api/Medikamente/search/Name/Ibuprophen
[HttpGet("search/Name/{name}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Medikament>>> Search(string name)
{
    return this._context.Medikament
        .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name))
        .ToList();
}

When I use https://localhost/api/mycontroller/search/Name/whatever everything works as intended and I get a collection of Medikaments. However when I provide an empty string, I get an HTTP-error:

"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"errors":{"name":["The name field is required."]},"traceId":"00-c02c1d252f699ee6612dc4b7d4ac29c7-20f9167159656762-00"}

The same applies when I omit the parameter completely:
https://localhost/mycontroller/search/Name/

How do I provide an empty string to the controller?

just add another path without {name}

@Komdosh wow, didn't know this was possible. Thank you

You have to set the request parameter name to nullable to allow empty string or null values.
// GET: api/Medikamente/search/Name/Ibuprophen
[HttpGet("search/Name/{name}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Medikament>>> Search(string? name)
{
     return this._context.Medikament
        .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name))
        .ToList();
}

Still, it's not working then also set route parameter to nullable also.
// GET: api/Medikamente/search/Name/Ibuprophen
[HttpGet("search/Name/{name?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Medikament>>> Search(string? name)
{
     return this._context.Medikament
        .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name))
        .ToList();
}

